# i want to convert into JS promise(Async/Await)

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

i want to use Async/await in the following code.

```
function Api(){
  
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users').then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => box.innerHTML=data.map((values) =>`<p>Login:${values.login}</p> 
                                                  <p>ID:${values.id}`).join(''))
}
```

Comment: Make `Api` an `async` function and use `await` instead of `.then()`. See [Making asynchronous programming easier with async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: i tried , but could not do it, should i wrap all it in a variables?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71245312/edit) to show what you tried

Comment: no...i am fairly new.

Answer (score -4):

you can try to do it like that

```js
async function Api () {
  let result = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users');
  result = await result.json();
  
  box.innderHTML = result.data.map((values => `<p>Login:${values.login}</p><p>ID:${values.id}`).join(''))
  
  }
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend overwriting `result`. Use a new variable like `data`

Comment: phil, can u show?

Comment: Eg `const data = await result.json()` and `box.innerHTML = data.map(...)`

Comment: FYI, OP's original JSON response doesn't have a `data` property so `result.data` in your answer will be undefined